# Identify number of new product combinations using R data.table

Tags: r, data.table, set, combinations

I am trying to solve a problem using data.table and unable to get my head around it. Here is the data.table that I have, which contains two columns -- products sold and basket id. Each letter denotes a product and basket id denotes a consumer basket.

```
df <- data.table(products = c("C" , "B" ,  "C", "A", "B" ,"C", "X", "B"), basket.id = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3))
```

Next, I create unique product combinations sold. i.e,

```
df[, product.combinations := paste0(unique(products), collapse = ";"), by = basket.id]
```

I get this table,

```
   products   basket.id    product.combinations
1:        C         1                  C;B
2:        B         1                  C;B
3:        C         2                  C;A
4:        A         2                  C;A
5:        B         3                B;C;X
6:        C         3                B;C;X
7:        X         3                B;C;X
8:        B         3                B;C;X
```

Now, I want to create a column -- if a new combination of product sold in a basket (order is not important i.e. C;B is equivalent to B;C) amongst all the baskets sold.

Therefore, I want to get to this table.

```
  products   basket.id    product.combinations  is.new.combo
1:        C         1                  C;B      0
2:        B         1                  C;B      0
3:        C         2                  C;A      1
4:        A         2                  C;A      1
5:        B         3                B;C;X      1
6:        C         3                B;C;X      1
7:        X         3                B;C;X      1
8:        B         3                B;C;X      1
```

Explanation: unique combinations are (C,B), (C,A), (B,C,X), however, (C,B) also is a part of the bigger basket 3 i.e. (B,C,X) therefore, it is not a new combination (and just a subset), therefore, is.new.combo = 0 .

Is there way I can do this in a data.table?

Comment: So if there is another basket which has combination `A;C;X` then everything would be 0?

Comment: How many products could you have in one basket?

Comment: Does this have to be ordered by `basket.id`? Say you have a new basket only containing `C` would this mean every following basket containing `C` (plus something else) is now regarded as a **not new** combination? Also would this basket containing only `C` then be a new basket itself, since no previous basket has contained `C` alone?

Comment: Does order matter? I would probably define `product.combinations` with `sort(unique(products))`

Comment: @RonakShah -- if A;C;X is available then in the last column the first four rows will be 0, 0, 0, 0, rest  will be 1. The third and fourth will be zero as the C;X is a subset of A;C;X as mentioned the order does not matter.

Comment: @MichaelChirico the order does not matter as mentioned in the question

Comment: @Oliver it does not require to be ordered by basket.id. All basket id needs to be considred and their order does not matter. if C is added it is a subset in the firts basket C;B therefore, can not be considered as a new combination.

Comment: @JosephWood -- currently there are no limits, but it would be finite and less than 1000 (in the actual dataset).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would try and define `product.combinations` in order, so that `A;X` and `X;A` don't show up as separate product combinations (unless that's intentional).

You could do this simply by adding `sort(unique(.))` to the aggregation, but actually this will invoke sort `uniqueN(basket.id)` times, so it's better to sort up front:

```
df[
  order(products), 
  product.combinations := paste(unique(products), collapse=';'), 
  by=basket.id
]
```

For your goal, I'm not sure the most efficient approach. A conservative approach is to start with the "biggest" combination, then add all possible subsets of that, "crossing off" any subsets that you observe. Here's one way to go:

```
# find all unique combinations
unique_combos = unique(df, by='product.combinations')
# it will be easier to work with as a list column than as a string
#   (though note, I keep the string, because data.table doesn't implement
#    merges on list columns, which we'll need later)
unique_combos[ , product.list := strsplit(product.combinations, ';', fixed=TRUE)]
# order by basket size
unique_combos[ , n_products := lengths(product.list)]
setorder(unique_combos, -n_products)[]
#    products basket.id product.combinations product.list n_products
# 1:        B         3                B;C;X        B,C,X          3
# 2:        C         1                  B;C          B,C          2
# 3:        C         2                  A;C          A,C          2
```

Now we add a flag, `is.new.combo`, defaulting to `TRUE`, and switch it to `FALSE` as we go along:

```
unique_combos[ , is.new.combo := TRUE]
```

Now loop:

```
# use a while loop because we'll skip some rows
for (ii in 1:nrow(unique_combos)) {
  # don't check subsets of rows we already know aren't "new"
  if (!unique_combos$is.new.combo[ii]) next
  
  # get all subsets of this row, except the "trivial" complete subset
  all_subsets = lapply(
    1:(unique_combos$n_products[ii] - 1L), 
    FUN=combn, x=unique_combos$product_list[[ii]], simplify=FALSE
  )
  # partially unnest this
  all_subsets = unlist(all_subsets, recursive=FALSE)
  # collapse to string form for easier comparison; I don't think sort() is
  #   required here but better to be safe
  all_subsets = sapply(all_subsets, function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse=';'))

  # now mark off the observed of these subsets
  unique_combos[product.combinations %chin% all_subsets, is.new.combo := FALSE]
}
```

Now we can confirm this worked, and merge it back to `df`:

```
# confirmation
unique_combos[]
#    products basket.id product.combinations product.list n_products is.new.combo
# 1:        B         3                B;C;X        B,C,X          3         TRUE
# 2:        C         1                  B;C          B,C          2        FALSE
# 3:        C         2                  A;C          A,C          2         TRUE

# merge back
df[unique_combos, on = 'product.combinations', is.new.combo := i.is.new.combo][]
#    products basket.id product.combinations is.new.combo
# 1:        C         1                  B;C        FALSE
# 2:        B         1                  B;C        FALSE
# 3:        C         2                  A;C         TRUE
# 4:        A         2                  A;C         TRUE
# 5:        B         3                B;C;X         TRUE
# 6:        C         3                B;C;X         TRUE
# 7:        X         3                B;C;X         TRUE
# 8:        B         3                B;C;X         TRUE
```